# Ember-Data: InnerObject has EmptyObjects - whats not true

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

Recently, I started to learn Ember-data and I'm writting an application with very custom API. 
Response from Back-end is in bad format, so i normalize it to JsonApi via method 'normalizeResponse' and everything works good.

The problem appears in moment when I want to see content from response. When I was reading about Ember-data, I learned that if got data (InnerObjects), I will be able to take property from it via.
InnerObject.get('some_property'), but it doesnt work for me. 
If I want 'some_property' I have to write InnerObject.data.someproperty what looks bad in longer path. I used Ember.debug() to see this path and my browser shows me that property '_data' is EmptyObject what is not true. When i click on it, it shows a list of properly content ( look attachment ). 
Am I doing something wrong ? Am I forget about something or misunderstood Ember-Data? 
I will be grateful for any help.

IMAGES:

- [Browser with _data -> EmptyObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6wFm.jpg)
- [Browser with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjUrl.jpg)

```js
export default DS.Model.extend({

  facebook: DS.attr(),
  www:  DS.attr(),
  name: DS.attr(),
  street: DS.attr(),
  house_number: DS.attr(),
  postal_code: DS.attr(),
  city: DS.attr(),
  province: DS.attr(),
  picture: DS.attr(),
  x: DS.attr(),
  y: DS.attr()

});
//json api serializer
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({

  normalizeArrayResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, this._normalizeSearch(payload), id, requestType);
  },

  _normalizeSearch(shops) {
    let data = shops.map((obj) => {
        return {
          type: "search",
          id: obj.id_sklep,
          attributes: {
            facebook: obj.facebook,
            www: obj.www,
            name: obj.nazwa_sklep,
            street: obj.adres_ulica,
            house_number: obj.adres_nr_domu,
            postal_code: obj.adres_kod,
            city: obj.adres_miasto,
            province: obj.adres_woj,
            picture: obj.zdjecie_sklep,
            x: obj.lat,
            y: obj.lng
          }
        };
    });

    return { data: data  } ;
  }

});

export default Ember.Service.extend({

  getShopsAndServices(pattern) {
    return this.get('store').query('search', {
      fraza: pattern,
      cena_min: 0,
      cena_max: 100,
      id_kat: 1,
      lat: 53,
      lng: 18
    });
  }
  
}

//Controller action: 
    searchRequest(pattern) {
      return pattern.length > this.MIN_CHARS_FOR_SEARCH ? this.get('search').getShopsAndServices(pattern).then((results) => {
        let content = results.get('content').length ? results.get('content') : [];
        if (content) {
          let foo = content[0];
          Ember.Logger.debug(foo)
          Ember.Logger.debug(foo._data.name)
          Ember.Logger.debug(foo.get('name'))
        }
        return this.set('content', results.get('content').length ? results.get('content') : []);
      }) : this.set('content', []);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InnerObject.data.someproperty`  => This is wrong.
`InnerObject.get('some_property')`  => this is right.

Update your question with not working code. so that we can identify the issue.

1.query method returns Promise and this will be resolved to DS.RecordArray which extends [Ember.ArrayProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html) so you can use all the methods available.

2.`results.get('content')` - Don't access `content` property,

3.You can convert that special array to normal array by `results.toArray()`

4.You can even use `each` helper to iterate it like normal array template which is returned by this `this.get('search').getShopsAndServices(pattern)`.